# How to make a long text fit into the legend box?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib 1.2.0 with Python 2.7 on OSX 10.8.3 and I have a plot like the following:

[image]

As you can see, there is a problem with the legend text on the right side which does not completely fit into the legend box. Changing the font size of the legend text does not help. Meanwhile, I've found out that the problem is with the PDF backend. Saving the plot as a JPEG, for example, the text fits perfectly into the box.

Here are the relevant code parts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(0, figsize=(10, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])

ax.plot(
    x, y,
    # I construct the labels dynamically like this 
    label=str(pr_auc_values[result_id])  + '  |  ' + filenames[result_id]
)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.15, box.width, box.height * 0.85])
plt.legend(loc='upper center', title='AUC Scores', fontsize=7, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1))

# Saving as PDF leads to overfitting text
# Saving as JPEG works fine, though
plt.savefig('my_beautiful_plot.pdf')
```

Which setting do I have to configure such that the legend box adapts itself to the length of the text?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. In Matplotlib 1.2 in Python 3.3, it works fine for me. I assume you use `ax.plot(x, y, label = label)`? Does it fit when you make the legend texts shorter?

Comment: @Robbert Exactly, I'm using `ax.plot(x, y, label=label)` to specify the labels of the legend. But I'm using Python 2.7. It even does not fit when I make the text shorter. Perhaps I should add that I join the labels dynamically in the plot command using `label=str(pr_auc_values[result_id])  + '  |  ' + filenames[result_id]`. Is that a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, but you can easily try it by just entering a string.

Comment: @Robbert No, doesn't fix it. But I've just found out that the problem is with the PDF backend. When I save the plot as a JPEG, for example, the text fits perfectly into the box. Weird. But I need my plots as PDFs. :-(

Comment: You're not using the default font, are you? Could that be the source of the (backend) problems?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom font. The default one is ugly. ;) But I cannot change the font as it would break the design of my entire project.

Comment: It would help to narrow down the problem. Otherwise, you could set `leg = plt.legend(..., borderpad = 1)`, which makes the frame a bit wider, or you can set `leg.set_frame_on(False)` to hide the frame.

Comment: I've already tried the `borderpad` option but to no avail. Disabling the frame is a workaround but I'd prefer to keep it. Maybe this is a bug on OSX.

Comment: You could make a [`rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) with `facecolor='none'` to replace it. You'll have to find the dimensions yourself.